# jquery simplecart php variables

Tags: php, jquery, simplecart

I'm having difficulties with the onclick jquery within my php code, how do I get a php variable so that name=variable and price=variable?

```
    <?php

    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM table");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<ul>';
      echo '<li>' . $row['selection'] . '<div style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add('name='. $row['selection'] . ','price='. $row['price'] .');return false;
     "> '. $row['price'] . '</a></div></li>';
      echo '</ul>';
      }

      ?>
```

How do I get around this? Thanks

Comment: Have you ever seen anyone call a function like `somefunc(param1='x', param2='y')`? Why not try `somefunc('x', 'y')`?

Comment: Learning basic PHP string syntax would be a good start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: @developerwjk I think I've seen people use php functions to do such things. I saw it on `count` the other day when I was referencing something. `count ( mixed $array_or_countable [, int $mode = COUNT_NORMAL ] )` however that isn't the way it actually formats. I can understand the confusion though. None the less it is wrong and OP needs to parse his variables differently and correctly. I can understand the confusion though.

Answer (score 0):

change your code with this line...

```
echo '<div style="float:right;"><a href="#"
onclick="simpleCart.add(name='.$row['selection'].',price='.$row['price'].')"
</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not faniliar with simplecart,  but You definitely need to crrectly escape your quotes.

```
<?php

    $result = mysqli_query($db,    "SELECT * FROM table");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<ul>'; 
        echo '<li>' . $row['selection'] . '<div style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add(\'name=\''. $row['selection'] . ',\'price=\''. $row['price'] . ');return false; "> '. $row['price'] . '</a></div></li>'; echo '</ul>'; }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.. `onclick="simpleCart.add(\'name='.$row['selection'].'\',`